# Extract fields from JSON file to rewrite it

Tags: python, json, field, extract

What is the best way in python 3 to process as generic as possible a json file in order to keep only some fields ?

The script has to take a list of fields to keep and rewrite the json file with only these. 
Without round on float and exactly the same type.

Exemple :

**Input file (newline delimited json):**

```
{"var_1":"result_1", "var_2": 11.2, "var_3": "result_3", "nested_obj" : { "var_4": 0.0000000333, "var_5" = "result_5"}}
{"var_1":"result_1", "var_2": 11.2, "var_3": "result_3", "nested_obj" : { "var_4": 0.0000000333, "var_5" = "result_5"}}
{"var_1":"result_1", "var_2": 11.2, "var_3": "result_3", "nested_obj" : { "var_4": 0.0000000333, "var_5" = "result_5"}}
{"var_1":"result_1", "var_2": 11.2, "var_3": "result_3", "nested_obj" : { "var_4": 0.0000000333, "var_5" = "result_5"}}
{"var_1":"result_1", "var_2": 11.2, "var_3": "result_3", "nested_obj" : { "var_4": 0.0000000333, "var_5" = "result_5"}}
```

**Args :**

fields_to_keep = ["var_1", "nested_obj.var_4"]

**Output file :**

```
{"var_1":"result_1","nested_obj" : { "var_4": 0.0000000333 }}
{"var_1":"result_1","nested_obj" : { "var_4": 0.0000000333 }}
{"var_1":"result_1","nested_obj" : { "var_4": 0.0000000333 }}
{"var_1":"result_1","nested_obj" : { "var_4": 0.0000000333 }}
{"var_1":"result_1","nested_obj" : { "var_4": 0.0000000333 }}
{"var_1":"result_1","nested_obj" : { "var_4": 0.0000000333 }}
```

With pandas or json libs there is a round on my float.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this in Python rather than `jq`?

Comment: Oh -- also, your stated input isn't valid JSON at all; `"var_5" = "whatever"` needs to have `:` instead of `=`.

Comment: A `jq` solution that emits correct output (the numbers are formatted in scientific notation, but they aren't rounded at all) is `jq -c --argjson keep '{"var_1": true, "nested_obj": true, "nested_obj.var_4": true}' 'fromstream(tostream | .[0] as $key_arr | ($key_arr | join(".")) as $key | select($keep[$key]?))' <<<"${s// = /: }"`, where `s` is the name of a shell variable with your input.

Comment: ...converting `["var1", "nested_obj.var_4"]` into `{"var1": true, "nested_obj": true, "nested_obj.var_4": true}` is admittedly an exercise left for the reader, but it's a pretty simple exercise.